# How to reshape an array of arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, numpy-ndarray

Using this function

```
def imRead (fold, file):
    image = Image.open(os.path.join(fold, file)).convert('L')
    image = image.resize((int(image.size[0]/100), int(image.size[1]/100)), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    imData = np.asanyarray(image.getdata()).reshape(image.size)
    return imData/255
```

I'm reading grey scale images into the column of a dataframe

```
data02 = data02.values
for j in range(0, len(data02)):
    data02[j][2] = imRead(train_image_path, data02[j][0])
```

then split image data and labels

```
X = data02[:,2]
Y = data02[:,1]
```

Finally, my **X is an array of arrays** with a length of number of images (20 for the test) and each element - array 210*140 (image size)
How can I reshape the X in order to feed it into Conv NN layer?

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (210,140,1)))
```

`X.reshape(20, 210,140,1)`
Gives an error `'cannot reshape array of size 20 into shape (20,210,140,1)'`
I tried to apply many other shapes but with no success since the primary array is just (20,) array.

**How to reshape array of arrays???**

Comment: You can use parameter ```-1``` to the axis you want to fit automatically

Comment: What is `data02`? Originally and after `values`?  What is `dtype` of `X`?

Comment: data02 is a dataframe where the first column is the image file name, the second - labels, the 3rd - image data

Comment: If `X` has shape (20,) and `dtype` `object`, you can't change it with `reshape`.  `reshape` does not 'reach-through' that 'object' boundary.  It's like you have a list of arrays.

Comment: So the 3rd column is an `object` dtype `Series`.  If the images are all the same size (including number of 'channels'). `np.stack(X)` should join them into a 3d (or 4d) array.  It's a cover function for `concatenate`.

Comment: You could use `np.frompyfunc` which is a bit like `map` for arrays. `np.frompyfunc(np.ndarray.reshape,4,1)(<your_array>,210,140,1)`